Best Practices for Managing Multiple Entity Types in ASP.NET Core
I'm working on an ASP.NET Core application that requires handling multiple types of a single entity. Each type has its own properties and validation rules, which has led to confusion and complexity in managing DTOs, validations, and controllers.

I’m using ASP.NET Core with Entity Framework and want to create a clean and maintainable architecture.
Each entity type has distinct validation requirements that complicate the DTO and controller structure.

Specific Questions

What are the best practices for creating and managing different DTOs for multiple entity types?
How should I approach validations to ensure they are both clear and efficient?
What design patterns or strategies can I implement to keep my controllers organized and manageable when dealing with multiple entity types?

I would appreciate any guidance, examples, or resources that can help me tackle this challenge effectively.

I don’t understand what you mean with “multiple types of a single entity”. An example would probably help.

How do you feel about my answer to your previous question on this topic?

@Ewan Yeah, I get it, but I don't know how to ignore the data when I still need to perform validation and other tasks.

@RikD I have entities like User, which has subclasses like Teacher, Student, etc., and Question, which has subclasses like MCQ, Essay, etc. Each type has its data that I need to validate in different ways.

@MarkoSami how do you mean? like in my example, since each action on a controller has different validation logic, you make a ValidationService object for each with the rules in and call its Validate(object) method. all your controllers will look the same, you can use global error handling and custom exceptions to get rid of try catch throws everywhere

maybe you could neaten up further with some custom attributes or clever generic methods to select the correct validation, but I think that would be a step too far. the extra complexity would become a burden

In the controller what type of data should I accept
for example
Task Create(SomeType QuestionData){...}
what should be this type so I endure that it can bind all different questions

Gona need more info. does SomeType have derived classes or something?

Yes i have Question, MCQ, Essay  and they all derive from Question

should i use question as the type or i should create a new type wich containes all different properties from all the question types

If you wan tto use the same action for all the types you are gona need some extra binding/json type info

I can do different actions for every type and have a function for every type in the questions service

If I understand you right you have the following classes:
Question
MultipleChoiceQuestion : Question
Essay : Question
.... : Question

And you want a single Create endpoint:
Post Create(Question q)

Which will validate and save to a database any of the derived Question types.
First off, .NET won't magically know which derived type to deserialise the incoming JSON to. You'll need to add some cleverness type discriminators.
This needs some $type field in the JSON, so:
Question
{
    public string Type => this.getType().ToString(); // I'm sure you can do better.
}

Now that you have the actual type in the controller you just need to select the validation logic. Given my previous answer where I stress the benefits of keeping the validation separate from the object, we want to avoid question.Validate().
QuestionController
{
    [HttpPost]
    public Task Create(Question q)
    {
        IValidator v;
        if(!this.ValidationDictionary.TryGetValue(q.Type + "_Create", out v))
        {
           throw new CantFindValidatorException(q.Type);
        }

        v.Validate(q); // throw validation exception with collection of error messages. handle in global exception handler which just converts to json and adds error code of your choice.
        this.repo.Add(q); //more looking at q.Type to decide which tables to put it in.

    }

}

Given the fiddlyness of this and the need to check the type in multiple places and ensure its sent in the JSON, You have to consider the alternative of just adding extra controller actions:
QuestionController
{
    [HttpPost]
    public Task CreateEssay(Essay q)
    {
         this.create(q);   
    }  
    [HttpPost]
    public Task CreateMCQ(MultipleChoiceQuestion q)
    {
         this.create(q);   
    }  

    private Task create(Question q)
    {
        IValidator v;
        if(!this.ValidationDictionary.TryGetValue(q.GetType(), out v))
        {
           throw new CantFindValidatorException(q.GetType() + "_Create");
        }

        v.Validate(q);
        select  q.GetType() //or factory pattern of choice
        case "Essay"
            this.repo.AddEssay(q);
        ...
    }
}

This approach levers the built in serialisation and route mapping.
